# How to set enable all radio groups from a loop in Java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, onclicklistener

The string `answers_log` is the result of a database query. So, when i loop trough the results, it generates 4 radio groups. When it try to set all radio groups enable, the `radioGroup.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);` is applied only to the last radio group. What can i do, to set all radio groups enable?
Here is my code:

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    for (Answer an : answers) {
        String answers_log = " " + an.getAnswer();
        answer = new RadioButton(this);
        answer.setText(answers_log);
        radioGroup.addView(answer+log);
    }
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);

    finishButton = new Button(this);
    linearLayout.addView(finishButton);

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
                }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a RadioGroup do not allow you to select multiple RadioButtons at same time. You should add 4 radio buttons without RadioGroup.

Comment: I don't want to select multiple radio buttons, i just need to set all radio groups enabled when i press a button.

Comment: Can you share some Ui ?

Comment: Everything is done dynamically. I added the layout, the radio buttons and radio groups programmatically. Do you have an idea?

Comment: yes i have idea but i was just confused why are you getting the element and setting it false. and you are not setting the whole radio group false.

Comment: Even if i do the whole radio group as you say, `setEnabled` is applied only to the last radio group. I need to set `setEnabled` to all 4 radio groups.

Comment: I need to see your UI because i am not getting your concept of radiogroups and radiobuttons.

Comment: The concept is very simple. I have 4 questions and 4 answers for each question. The question is a TextView and the 4 answers are the 4 radio buttons nested in a radio group. So, when i press the button, i want all radio buttons to be disabled. Now the problem is that the `setEnabled` is applied only to the last radio group.
`<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
</ScrollView>`

Comment: ok. Your for () loop is running against just one radio group. you need a nested for loop on for radio group and one for radiobuttons,